# Multiple items selection in grid view getting repeated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, gridview, multipleselection

[This is the first grid where I selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNJDg.jpg)

the problem is: 
[when I scroll down, here random images are getting selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYj9f.jpg)

I used glide library for grid view. Here's the Java Code for Multiple selection:

```
mgridview.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int i, long l, boolean b) {
            if (sel_tab2_images.contains(tab2_images.get(i))) {
                sel_count = sel_count - 1;
                actionMode.setTitle(sel_count + " images selected");
                sel_tab2_images.remove(tab2_images.get(i));
                viewprev = mgridview.getChildAt(i - mgridview.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                viewprev.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                viewprev.setAlpha(1f);
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=23) {
                    viewprev.setForeground(null);
                }


            } else {
                sel_count = sel_count + 1;
                actionMode.setTitle(sel_count + " images selected");
                sel_tab2_images.add(tab2_images.get(i));


                viewprev = mgridview.getChildAt(i - mgridview.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                if (viewprev != null) {

                    viewprev.setAlpha(0.5f);

                  //ImageView imageView=viewprev.findViewById(R.id.tick);

                   //Resource(R.drawable.ic_save_black_24dp);
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=23) {
                        viewprev.setForeground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_check_white_24dp));
                    }







                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }






        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = actionMode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_action_bar, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
            int del_count = 0;
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.delete_action_bar:
                    for (String sel : sel_tab2_images) {
                        file = new File(sel);
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            file.delete();
                            tab2_images.remove(sel);
                            if (tab1_fragment.tab1_images.contains(sel)) {
                                tab1_fragment.tab1_images.remove(sel);
                            }
                            if (tab3_fragment.spam_list.contains(sel)) {
                                tab3_fragment.spam_list.remove(sel);
                            }
                            UpdateGallery(sel);
                            /*
                            int pos_1=tab2_images.indexOf(sel);
                            tab2_images.remove(sel);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            viewprev=mgridview.getChildAt(pos_1);
                            viewprev.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                            */

                            del_count++;
                        }
                    }

                    adapter = new ImageAdapterGridView(getContext());
                    mgridview.setAdapter(adapter);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), del_count + " images deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    sel_count = 0;
                    sel_tab2_images.clear();
                    actionMode.finish();
                    break;
            }

            return true;


        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
        }
    });





    return view;


}
```

Below is the java code for Grid View. I also tried @overriding `getItem` and `getItemId` methods but it's not working. This is my first app and I'm still learning. Please help me to fix this!

```
public class ImageAdapterGridView extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mcontext;

    public ImageAdapterGridView(Context c) {
        mcontext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return tab2_images.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if(convertview==null){
            imageView= new ImageView(mcontext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(280,320));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(16,16,16,16);
        }
        else{
            imageView=(ImageView)convertview;
        }
        Glide.with(tab2_fragment.this).load("file://" + tab2_images.get(position))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(imageView);

        return imageView;
    }

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapter = new ImageAdapterGridView(getContext());
    mgridview.setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're relying on view in a list. In list views are being reused as they get off screen. So to get this done you have to declare a `boolean isSelected` per each item (so the best place to do this is in your item model which holds all each grid properties) and make it true as the user select your grid item and always update your view based on *that* boolean **not** the view.

Currently your model is holding just the url of your images. If you need to save the `isSelected` boolean there you should build your model object like:

```
public class ImageModel {
    public String url;
    public boolean isSelected;
}
```

And then use the field objects in your grid list:

```
public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int i, long l, boolean b) {
    ImageModel image = tab2_images.get(i);
    if (image.isSelected) {
        // Image is selected you need to deselect it
    } else {
        // Image is not selected you need to select it
    }
}
```

In your adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Your view construction code

    ImageModel image = tab2_images.get(i);
    if (image.isSelected) {
        // Show your check image view
    } else {
        // Image is not selected yet, hide your check image view
    }
}
```

I hope this helps but grid view is considered deprecated, try to consider using [`RecyclerView`](https://shawn-duan.com/android/recyclerview/2016/06/14/Multi-Selection-Mode-for-RecyclerView/) which is more efficient and fast.

Comment: i tried keeping isSelected before the "viewprev=mgridview.getChidAt(i-getFirstVisiblePosition());" But it's not working. I know problem is in above line. Please elaborate your answer!

Comment: @Bvs sorry for the delay, see my updated answer. Hope it gives you the clue.